# Programa de inversion con tabla de tabulacion y arreglos uni o bidimensionales

Tags: c++, array, estructuras-de-datos

Es un ejercicio de la escuela sobre uso de arreglos en c++ aunque no logro comprender cómo acomodar que el ejercicio me muestre tabulación del mes y el total acumulado y la ganancia total acumulada al finalizar el plazo.

```
-----------------------------------------------------
% mensual| *monto ingresado por usuario (ej. %2.0)  |
-----------------------------------------------------
|   mes  |  cantidad  |   total acumulado           |
-----------------------------------------------------
  enero  | 1000       |   1000
 febrero |            |   1020                
                          1040
```

.... y asi consecutivamente hasta diciembre

El problema es:

> Una persona desea invertir cierta cantidad de dinero (por ejemplo        $1000.00) en el banco, el cual le otorga un cierto porcentaje de interés mensual (por ejemplo 2.0%).
>
> La persona, desea saber cuál será la cantidad de dinero que se tendrá al  cabo de un año si todo el dinero lo reinvierte. (Tip: considere cada mes como un contador que se aumenta en 1 cada vez que se repite el ciclo).
>
> Al final se deberá imprimir en pantalla el saldo total con el porcentaje de interés (en esta caso 2%) de cada mes y su ganancia obtenida al finalizar el plazo ( en éste ejemplo 1 año = 12 meses).

El codigo para ingresar variables como monto de inversion, plazo, interes mensual de ejecucion es:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#define SIN_TIPO string         
int main() {
float capital;
float ganancia;
float porcentaje;
int plazo;


cout << " ingrese el capital" << endl;
cin >> capital;
cout << "ingrese porcentajem ensual" << endl;
cin >> porcentaje;
cout << "ingrese plazo" << endl;
cin >> plazo;
ganancia = capital*porcentaje;

cout << "La ganancia es:" << ganancia << endl;
return 0;
}
```

¿Algun consejo?

Answer (score 1):

Lo primero es que esa tabla está mal hecha. Si los intereses se añaden al capital, que es lo que se entiende por *reinvertir*. Lo que se consigue es el interés compuesto y no funciona añadiendo una cantidad fija (según tu ejemplo) de 20 por mes.

```
         Capital  Intereses        Total
Enero     1000,0       20,0       1020
Febrero   1020,0       20,4       1040,4   <<---  0,4 respecto a tu ejemplo
Marzo     1040,4       20,8       1061,2   <<---  1,2 respecto a tu ejemplo
```

El caso es que para sacar estos resultados no necesitas ni arrays ni estructuras de datos, sino única y exclusivamente un bucle, que debería realizar 12 iteraciones (una por cada mes del año).

Para tabular los datos tienes a tu disposición la librería `iomanip`. Un ejemplo:

```
int main()
{
  // setw establece el numero de caracteres del siguiente campo
  // el valor de setw hay que establecerlo en cada uso
  std::cout << std::setw(10) << "Mes"
            << std::setw(10) << "Capital"
            << std::setw(10) << "Intereses"
            << std::setw(10) << "Total"
            << '\n'
            << std::setprecision(2) // numeros con dos decimales
            << std::fixed;          // para que no salga notacion cientifica
                                    // a diferencia de setw, estos valores no se pierden

  float capital = 1000;
  float const interes = 0.02;

  for( int i=0; i<12; i++ )
  {
    float intereses = capital * interes;
    float total = capital + intereses;

    std::cout << std::setw(10) << i
              << std::setw(10) << capital
              << std::setw(10) << intereses
              << std::setw(10) << total
              << '\n';

    capital = total;
  }
}
```

Lo de ponerle nombre al mes, te toca hacerlo a ti, no te voy a dar todo el ejercicio hecho.

Comment: Gracias eferion, buscare mas info de iomanip para comprender esta libvreria y como cuadrar todos los consejos que me diste con los bucles, iteraciones y lo que debo solucionar.

Answer (score 0):

Bienvenide a StackOverflow.

Parece que lo que te piden es hacer un arreglo de los meses y utilizar un ciclo `for` para mostrarlos. Ejemplo.

```
// Vector de meses
vector<string> meses {"Enero", "Febrero", "Marzo", "Abril", "Mayo", "Junio", "Julio", "Agosto", "Septiembre", "Octubre", "Noviembre", "Diciembre"};

for(int i = 0; i < meses.size(); i++) {
    cout << meses[i] << endl;
}
```

En este caso utilicé un `vector` y no un arreglo por simplicidad, pero para tu problema funciona exactamente igual. Es un objeto que almacena cadenas de texto. Contiene 12 cadenas de texto diferentes y su indice comienza en cero.

```
meses[0]  -> Enero
meses[1]  -> Febrero
meses[11] -> Diciembre
```

Ahora, tu tarea implica hacer algún cálculo matemático en cada iteración del ciclo `for`. Así como lo indica tu problema **"considere cada mes como un contador que se aumenta en 1 cada vez que se repite el ciclo"**.

Te recomiendo que hagas el cálculo matemático correspondiente a la solución de tu problema dentro del ciclo for e imprimas el resultado con el objeto cout. Ejemplo:

```
for(int i = 0; i < meses.size(); i++) {
    cout << meses[i] << "|" << ganancia * capital << endl;
}
```

Te comento que StackOverflow no es un sitio para que alguien resuelva tareas por ti, pero si puedes consultar ayuda en problemas con tu código.

Comment: Gracias akko, si tenia considerado esta estructura de :

meses[0]  -> Enero
meses[1]  -> Febrero
meses[11] -> Diciembre..

Comment: Gracias akko, si tenia considerado esta estructura de :

meses[0]  -> Enero
meses[1]  -> Febrero
meses[11] -> Diciembre..

Se que los users de stacoverflow no estan ni estamos para dar una solucion al 100% sino una guia o consejo para que lleguemos a ese resultado.

De verdada agradezco los comentarios, por que justo eso me hacia falta, un punto de partida para poder ampliar el enfoque que tenia. De verdad estaba sin ideas porque llevaba un rato haciendo que parte por parte fuera funcionando. :P Cuando algo funcionaba otra cosa no...